# chmod recursive, but exclude starting directory

Tags: linux, debian, redhat, file-permissions, chmod

From what I can tell, I've run into a limitation of chmod - hoping to pick the more experienced brains here before resorting to writing some find scripts.

I would like to chmod -R all files & directories within a folder, but leave the folder itself alone. I need to avoid the permissions of the starting directory changing, at all during this process, so a simple chmod -R followed by a non recursive chmod to reset the permissions on the starting directory isn't an option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply give `chmod` all the files and subdirectories inside the directory, rather than the directory itself. This is easily done with a glob pattern:

```
chmod -R dir/*
```

If you want to account for hidden files and dirs, you can `shopt -s dotglob` in bash.

Comment: Thank you - I feel silly now, answer was so obvious.